# R Converting contour lines to elevation plot

Tags: r, gis, rgdal, r-maptools, r-sp

I would like to be able to create an elevation plot from contour lines in R. I am very new to using shape files

At the moment I have downloaded data from [here](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html)
 which provides .shp files for all of the UK.

It also provides the contour lines, summarising the topology of the UK.

For the elevation plot I would like a `data.frame` or `data.table` of evenly spaced points (100m apart from each other) to produce a data output giving an x, y and z value. Where x and y represent the latitude and longitude (or Eastings and Northings), and z represent the height (in meters above sea-level).

I think there are probably some tools that will automatically carry out the interpolation for you, but am unsure how it would work with geo-spatial data.

This is my basic start...

```
require(maptools)
xx <- readShapeSpatial("HP40_line.shp")
```

Comment: You should directly download the grid version and use the `raster` package to upscale the data and get a SpatialPointsDataFrame.

Comment: Can you please show me how that would be done?

Comment: I'm not sure what a grid version is but don't think its available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose "ASCII Grid and GML (Grid)" as download format for the "OS Terrain 50" product, and download the file. This will give you a zip file containing many directories of zip files, each of which contains portions of a 50 m elevation grid of the UK (the portion I looked at had 200 x 200 cells, meaning 10 km x 10 km). I went into the directory `data/su`, unzipped the zip file there, and did

```
library(raster)
r = raster("SU99.asc")
plot(r)
```

to aggregate this to a 100 m grid, I did

```
r100 = aggregate(r) # default is factor 2: 50 -> 100 m
```

As mentioned above, the advice is to work on the grids as contour lines are derived from grids, working the other way around is a painful and a great loss of information.

Getting grid values in longitude latitude as a `data.frame` can be done in two ways:

```
df = as.data.frame(projectRaster(r, crs = CRS("+proj=longlat")), xy = TRUE)
```

unprojects the grid to a new grid in longitude / latitude. As these grids cannot coincide, it minimally moves points (see ?projectRaster).

The second option is to convert the grid to points, and unproject these to longitude latitude, by

```
df2 = as.data.frame(spTransform(as(r, "SpatialPointsDataFrame"), CRS("+proj=longlat")))
```

This does not move points, and as a consequence does not result in a grid.

Comment: I don't see a .grd type file...i only see .asc .gml and .prj

Comment: Also how do i get the data.frame with the three columns of lat, long, altitude?

Comment: you are right: extension is `.asc`, not `.grd`, I corrected the answer above; you can get the `data.frame` by `as.data.frame(r100, xy = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for that, that is very useful. So I noticed that when carrying out `as.data.frame(r100, xy = TRUE)` the x and y values are not latitude and longitude, how would I convert it to be so...

Comment: OK, I added this to the answer.